# Wordpress creating special sub page with an index of posts

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a wordpress blog, I have set the front page to a Page instead of a series of posts. Now I want to create an index of the most recent posts on a sub page. For example I want to list the recent posts when a user types in /domain.com/articles/ and show a page when someone types in /domain.com/

I do not want to use a plugin, I would like to code this directly in to the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new page with articles for the slug (ie www.domain.com/articles where articles is the 'slug'), you can create custom template file called page-articles.php in your theme that will style the articles page.  You can then transfer the loop code from index.php into page-articles.php.